# Show different records in table on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a website where i have two divs that acts as button. I have two table in my database namely 'users' and 'stores'. I would like to show the tables based on the button clicked. Is there a way to achieve this without a page reload and without using ajax if possible.

below is the code i used for the buttons.

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="btn_container">
    <div class="buttons" id="btn_products"><i class="fas fa-store"></i>
      <h1 class="products_text">Total Products</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons" id="btn_users"><i class="fas fa-users"></i>
      <h1 class="users_text">Total Users</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">btn3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table_container">
    <!--the table should be loaded here-->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have two tables on the page, show/hide the respective table when a button is clicked. Why not use buttons as buttons?

Comment: The function you describe requires a whole lot more parts than a few html div. You'll need a server side implementation to pull users and stores out of database, return them over http/https in some format like json, and a javascript function to put that json into your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Ajax you have no other choice to have all tables in your HTML code when the page is loaded.

Here is what I propose

```js
const tables = [...document.getElementsByClassName('table')];

[...document.getElementsByClassName('buttons')].forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    const id = button.id.replace('btn_', '');
    tables.forEach(table => {
      table.style.display = table.id === id ? 'block' : '';
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn_container">
  <div class="buttons" id="btn_products"><i class="fas fa-store"></i>
    <h1 class="products_text">Total Products</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons" id="btn_users"><i class="fas fa-users"></i>
    <h1 class="users_text">Total Users</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">btn3</div>
</div>
<div class="table_container">
  <table class="table" id="products">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Table products</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table class="table" id="users">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Table users</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Note that if you want one of the two table to be shown when the page is loaded change the CSS to

```
#products /* #users */ {
   display: none 
}
```